# Gateway laptop NV57H77u suddenly died

Tags: battery

My [Gateway laptop NV57H77u](http://www.pcworld.com/product/1302466/gateway-nv57h77u-b814g32mnkk-notebook.html) suddenly died while I had my iPhone plugged into the USB to charge it’s battery. I had the laptop plugged into AC power during this time. After a very short period of time the laptop went black and I have been unable to restart it. Does the battery need to be replaced?

Answer (score 1):

No, if the laptop is plugged in its not using the battery for power so a dead battery would not cause the laptop to power off. I would check the USB port for any damage. If there is any damage the prongs could be grounding out the power preventing it from turning on.